# PowerShell: Create Script to MSTSC into by hostname, if DNS Fails, Use IP

Tags: powershell

Good Day All,

I am writing a script to make my life easier at work (whole reason for scripts). I am new to PowerShell, but I am currently self teaching.  Right now I have a text based menu script. I have a choice to remote into computer using MSTSC by computer name AND a choice to remote into the computer using MSTSC by IP.

This was my original script to get my ideas going, but now in clean-up mode... I would like to combine them into one option and make it where if DNS fails for any reason, it will try the IP. I have provided my script (I know, it is probally a mess. Remember, I am 100% self-taught and working on figuring out to how clean this up). I am open to other suggestions as well.

Thanks in advance!

```
########################
## Get Computer Info ##
########################

<# 
Description: This script will provide remote computer info.

Put together by: Allen Scott
#>

<# Change Log
Modified: 10/9/2018
Cleaning Up Script:
#>

# Set Console Environment
$host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = "Tech Support"
$Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor = ($bckgrnd = 'Black')
$Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = 'Cyan'
$Host.PrivateData.ErrorForegroundColor = 'DarkRed'
$Host.PrivateData.ErrorBackgroundColor = $bckgrnd
$Host.PrivateData.WarningForegroundColor = 'Red'
$Host.PrivateData.WarningBackgroundColor = $bckgrnd
$Host.PrivateData.DebugForegroundColor = 'Yellow'
$Host.PrivateData.DebugBackgroundColor = $bckgrnd
$Host.PrivateData.VerboseForegroundColor = 'blue'
$Host.PrivateData.VerboseBackgroundColor = $bckgrnd
$Host.PrivateData.ProgressForegroundColor = 'Gray'
$Host.PrivateData.ProgressBackgroundColor = $bckgrnd


cls
Write-host " "

"

  ______          __       _____                              __ 
 /_  __/__  _____/ /_     / ___/__  ______  ____  ____  _____/ /_
  / / / _ \/ ___/ __ \    \__ \/ / / / __ \/ __ \/ __ \/ ___/ __/
 / / /  __/ /__/ / / /   ___/ / /_/ / /_/ / /_/ / /_/ / /  / /_  
/_/  \___/\___/_/ /_/   /____/\__,_/ .___/ .___/\____/_/   \__/  
                                  /_/   /_/                      

"
Write-host -ForegroundColor green "*********************************************************************************************************************" 
Write-host  -ForegroundColor green "                                      Welcome to the Tech Support Computer Information Script.`n
                                      ----------------------------------------------------------`n
This Script is used for gathering remote computer information (Serial Number, MAC Address, IP, Windows Version, Etc).`n
Also, this script can be used to check connectivity and open the file explorer of the remote computer.`n
You can end this script at any time by pressing 'CTRL + C'. `n
After each process, it will also ask if you want to do another. `n  "
Write-host -ForegroundColor green "*********************************************************************************************************************"
Write-host -ForegroundColor green " "



#Set Window Title Bar
$computer = Read-Host "Enter Computer Name "    
cls
do {
cls
Write-host " "
Write-host " "

" 

  ______          __       _____                              __ 
 /_  __/__  _____/ /_     / ___/__  ______  ____  ____  _____/ /_
  / / / _ \/ ___/ __ \    \__ \/ / / / __ \/ __ \/ __ \/ ___/ __/
 / / /  __/ /__/ / / /   ___/ / /_/ / /_/ / /_/ / /_/ / /  / /_  
/_/  \___/\___/_/ /_/   /____/\__,_/ .___/ .___/\____/_/   \__/  
                                  /_/   /_/                      

"

    # Reset Window Title
    $host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = "Tech Support - $computer Menu"

    # Ask admin what process to start (Only allow the characters "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8"
    $process = Read-host "`nWhat would you like to do with $computer ? `n(1) Check Connectivity  (2) Sonar  (3) Get IP (4) Get MAC`n(5) Open Backdoor (6) Remote In (7) Full Computer Info (8) New Computer"

# Ensures only 1-8 are inputted
    while("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8" -notcontains $Process)
        {
            Write-host -ForegroundColor red "Invalide Response. Please choose 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8"
            $Process = Read-host "`nWhat would you like to do with $computer ? `n(1) Check Connectivity  (2) Sonar  (3) Get IP (4) Get MAC`n(5) Open Backdoor (6) Remote In (7) Full Computer Info (8) New Computer"
        }

    #If [1] is selected, Start check Connectivity
    If ($process -eq 1) 
        {

            Write-host -ForegroundColor green "`nStarting Check Connectivty`n"
            # Set new title
            $host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = "Tech Support - Check Connectivity"


            # Start Connectivity Check
             If (Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -Quiet)
                {
                    Write-Host "$computer is Online" -ForegroundColor Green
                } 
                else 
                {
                    Write-Host "$computer is offline" -ForegroundColor Red
                }

            #Pause for Display
            write-host " "
            pause
            $goToStart = "y"
        } 

    #If [2] is selected, Start Sonar
    If ($process -eq 2) 
        {

            Write-host ""
            Write-host -ForegroundColor green "`nStarting Sonar Process`n"

            $host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = "Tech Support -  Sonar"

            #Start SONAR

            Write-Host "Pinging $computer by sonar . . . "
            do
                { 
                    if (Test-Connection -count 1 -quiet -computer $computer)
                        {

                            [console]::beep(800,800)
                            Write-Host "$computer is Online!" -ForegroundColor Green
                            Start-Sleep -s 2
                        } 
                    else
                        {
                        [console]::beep(500,60)
                        Write-Host "$computer is Offline!" -ForegroundColor Red            
                        }
                }
            until (Test-Connection -count 1 -quiet -computer $computer)

            #Pause for Display
            write-host " "
            pause
            $goToStart = "y"

        }

    #If [3] is selected, Get IP Address     
    If ($process -eq 3) 
        {

            Write-host ""
            Write-host -ForegroundColor green  "`nStarting Get IP Address Process`n"
            $host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = "Tech Support -  Checking IP Address "

            Write-host ""
            $ip = Test-Connection $computer -count 1 | select Address,Ipv4Address

            Write-host $ip

            #Pause for Display
            write-host " "
            pause
            $goToStart = "y"
        }
    #If [4] is selected, Get Mac.  
    If ($process -eq 4) 
        {

            Write-host ""
            Write-host -ForegroundColor green "`nStarting Get MAC Process`n"
            $host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = "Tech Support -  Get MAC "

            $computerMAC = Get-WmiObject -ClassName Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "IPEnabled='True'" -ComputerName $Computer | Select-Object -Property MACAddress
            Write-Host $computerMAC

            #Pause for Display
            write-host " "
            pause
            $goToStart = "y"

        }
    #If [5] is selected, open remote file explorer
    If ($process -eq 5) 
        {
            Write-host ""
            Write-host -ForegroundColor green "`nStarting remote file explorer Process`n"
            $host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = "Tech Support -  Open remote file explorer "

            start \\$computer\c$

            #Pause for Display
            write-host " "
            pause
            $goToStart = "y"                
        }

    #If [6] is selected, set new computer name
    If ($process -eq 6) 
        {
            $User="admUser"
            cmdkey /generic:TERMSRV/$Computer /user:$User
            mstsc /v:$computer
            $goToStart = "y"
        }  

    #If [7] is selected, display full Computer information
    If ($process -eq 7) 
        {

            Write-host ""
            Write-host -ForegroundColor green "`nFull Computer Info Process`n"
            $host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = "Tech Support -  Full Computer Info "

            #Set Variables
            $computerSystem = get-wmiobject Win32_ComputerSystem -Computer $Computer
            $computerMAC = Get-WmiObject -ClassName Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "IPEnabled='True'" -ComputerName $Computer | Select-Object -Property MACAddress
            $computerBIOS = get-wmiobject Win32_BIOS -Computer $Computer
            $computerOS = get-wmiobject Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer $Computer
            $computerVersion = If ($computerOS.BuildNumber -eq "16299") {
                '1709'
                 } ElseIf ($computerOS.BuildNumber -eq "15063") {
                    '1703'
                 } ElseIf ($computerOS.BuildNumber -eq "14393") {
                    '1607'
                 }Else {
                    'Need to Update If Table for ' + $computerOS.BuildNumber
                }
            $computerCPU = get-wmiobject Win32_Processor -Computer $Computer
            $computerHDD = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $Computer -Filter drivetype=3

            #Output Details
            write-host "System Information for: " $computerSystem.Name -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Green
            "-------------------------------------------------------"
            "Manufacturer: " + $computerSystem.Manufacturer 
            "Model: " + $computerSystem.Model
            "Serial Number: " + $computerBIOS.SerialNumber
            "   " + $computerMAC
            "CPU: " + $computerCPU.Name
            "HDD Capacity: "  + "{0:N2}" -f ($computerHDD.Size/1GB) + "GB"
            "HDD Space: " + "{0:P2}" -f ($computerHDD.FreeSpace/$computerHDD.Size) + " Free (" + "{0:N2}" -f ($computerHDD.FreeSpace/1GB) + "GB)"
            "RAM: " + "{0:N2}" -f ($computerSystem.TotalPhysicalMemory/1GB) + "GB"
            "Operating System: " + $computerOS.caption + ", Service Pack: " + $computerOS.ServicePackMajorVersion + ", OS Version: " + $computerVersion
            "User logged In: " + $computerSystem.UserName
            "Last Reboot: " + $computerOS.ConvertToDateTime($computerOS.LastBootUpTime)
            ""
                "-------------------------------------------------------"

            #Pause for Display
            write-host " "
            pause
            $goToStart = "y"

        }

    #If [8] is selected, set new computer name
    If ($process -eq 8) 
        {

        $computer = Read-Host "Enter Computer Name: "
        $goToStart = "y"


    }

    } while ($goToStart -eq "Y") cls
```

Comment: Is your goal to create something like [Terminals](https://github.com/terminals-Origin/Terminals) ? Is the user going to be selecting a machine from a list, or, are they going to be entering the machine name in? Also, if you are wanting to have a sort of backup to IP address, you would need to have a list of IP Addresses associated with each machine. Seeing if name resolution fails you will need to know what IP Address it is (and hopefully it is static). One possibly is to import from a CSV. Currently, your script is just setting colors, it is not addressing the end goal.

Comment: Computer name will be manually entered each time.  Was hoping that we can query the DNS Server for last know IP address for that hostname. No Importing or list of IPs.  I have provided my entire script.  It does a lot right now.  You may need to scroll the script to see the rest.  Thank you for your reply.

Comment: my bad, I didnt scroll down. I'll look at it and post back

Comment: What I would do in this case, after `$computer = Read-Host "Enter Computer Name " ` (line 58). I would add: `$ipaddress = [System.Net.DNS]::GetHostAddresses($computer) ` . The later on if you wanted to use the IPaddress, let's say after a `if(Test-Connection){}` failed, then you would just call `$ipaddress.IPaddressToSTring` for the IP address.

Comment: Also, just a suggestion, on line 206, I would change this to `$User=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name ` This will start the session as the current user

Comment: Awesome. In the morning, I will try out your suggestions.  Thank you again for your responses!

Comment: Also, just thinking of this, can I use the WindowsIdentity function to open the C$ of the remote machine as well?  start \\$computer\c$

Comment: @jrider , that looks like it did the trick.  Now just trying to get the ability to pass the credentials to my backdoor section. ($computer\C$)  thanks again!

Comment: You can just append `-Credential [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name ` after `start \\$computer\C$`

Answer (score 0):

> What I would do in this case, after $computer = Read-Host "Enter
>   Computer Name " (line 58). I would add: $ipaddress =
>   [System.Net.DNS]::GetHostAddresses($computer) . The later on if you
>   wanted to use the IPaddress, let's say after a if(Test-Connection){}
>   failed, then you would just call $ipaddress.IPaddressToSTring for the
>   IP address. – jrider

Thanks for all your help!